# MySQL not superior (!>) operator

Tags: mysql, request, operator-keyword

is there an equivalent to the operator !> (not superior) in MySQl?
If not, what can I use instead?

Thank you

Comment: exactly where have you see `!>` being used?

Comment: thank you an sorry, I'm tired...

Comment: Marc B, in SQL : https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms184364(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just use `NOT` clause, like this:

```
select * from MyTable where NOT MyField > 10
```

or

```
select * from MyTable where MyField <= 10
```